# Nested component wont receive types passed down by parent

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, nested

I am trying to assemble a table that will be updated through actions resolved by backend, so for this reason I need to be able to pass the endpoint and the response model , when I try to nest and pass the response type it somehow gets lost in children components.

brief schematic TableParent.ResT -> TableChild ProviderForUpdates DataHandler.ResT\ // needs this to know under how to deal with the data ProviderForUpdates/ TableChild

Wanted scenario ParentComponent -will pass down the Type of Response - DataHandlerChild will inherit it and make the queries to update table - Children will update accordingly

Thanks for your help in advance

```
import { useState } from "react"; import DataTable from 

"@components/dataTable"; type CarTypes = { id: number; name: string; description: string; }; interface ResponseType { id: number; carTypes: CarTypes[]; }

const CarTypeComponent = () = >{
    const[carTypes, setCarTypes] = useState < ResponseType[] > ([]);
    return ( < ><DataTable < ResponseType > endpoint = "car_types"setIdsSelected = { (ids: number[]) = >setIdsSelected(ids)
    }
    idsSelected = {
        idsSelected
    }
    onRowClick = {
        handleRowClick
    }
    />
    </ > );
};

const DataTable = <ResponseType,
>({
    setIdsSelected,
    idsSelected,
    onRowClick,
    endpoint,
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars, @typescript-eslint/no-empty-function, react/prop-types
    onSort = (column: string, dir: "asc" | "desc" | "") = >{},
}: Props) = >{
    return (< >{
    } < TableContentProvider > {
        /* for reasons beyond my knowledge type doesnt arrives here */
    } < TableDataHandler < ResponseType > setIdsSelected = {
        setIdsSelected
    }
    idsSelected = {
        idsSelected
    }
    onSort = {
        onSort
    }
    onRowClick = { (id: number) = >{
            onRowClick(id);
        }
    }
    endpoint = {
        endpoint
    }
    />
      </TableContentProvider > </>
  );
};

const TableDataHandler = <ResponseType,>({
  setIdsSelected,
  idsSelected,
  onSort,
  onRowClick,
  endpoint,
}: TableDataHandlerProps<ResponseType>) => {
  const { currentSortedColumn, queryString } = useTableContext();
  const {
        response,
        error,
        loading
    } = useAxios < ResponseType > ({
        url: `$ {
            endpoint
        }
        s ? $ {
            queryString
        }`,
        method: Methods.GET,
    });
    return ( < >{
        response && <TableCore < typeof tableData.data > />
        }
    </ > );
};
```

Comment: Please provide a properly formatted code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

you can not pass props like that try something simpler

```
function CarTypeComponent({ ids }: { ids: number[] }) {
  const [carTypes, setCarTypes] = useState([]);
  const [idsSelected, setIdsSelected] = useState<number[]>([]);

  const handleIdSelected = () => {
    setIdsSelected(ids);
  };

  return (
    <DataTable setIdsSelected={handleIdSelected} endpoint="/api/carTypes" />
  );
}
```